# Binding to static property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm having a hard time binding a simple static string property to a TextBox.

Here's the class with the static property:

```csharp
public class VersionManager
{
    private static string filterString;

    public static string FilterString
    {
        get { return filterString; }
        set { filterString = value; }
    }
}
```

In my xaml, I just want to bind this static property to a TextBox:

```XML
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Source="{x:Static local:VersionManager.FilterString}"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Everything compiles, but at run time, I get the following exception:

> Cannot convert the value in attribute
>   'Source' to object of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension'.
>   Error at object
>   'System.Windows.Data.Binding' in
>   markup file
>   'BurnDisk;component/selectversionpagefunction.xaml'
>   Line 57 Position 29.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

If the binding needs to be two-way, you must supply a path.

There's a trick to do two-way binding on a static property, provided the class is not static : declare a dummy instance of the class in the resources, and use it as the source of the binding.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:VersionManager x:Key="versionManager"/>
</Window.Resources>
...

<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource versionManager}, Path=FilterString}"/>
```

Comment: This answer is more appropriate to my case because I don't want to introduce DependencyObject to my source class. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Note that will enable your text box to push the value back into the static property, but will not update the textbox when the source value changes.

Comment: That's fine, I just needed the binding from the textbox to the Source in this case. If I want the binding to work the other way, I'm aware of the need for one of these methods: INotifyPropertyChanged, <PropertyName>Changed event or dependency property.

Comment: Note: This solution won't work in an MVVM situation, as you generally don't have access to the types of the objects you're binding to.

Comment: @thomas  I would love to get this to work for me but cannot.  I posted my dilemma as another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656670/my-static-model-property-is-not-binding-to-my-ui

Comment: Doesn't this count as One-way if it doesn't update the textbox?

Comment: @user1034912 could you elaborate? this solution worked for me, for the OP and for many others..

Answer (score 130):

You can't bind to a static like that. There's no way for the binding infrastructure to get notified of updates since there's no `DependencyObject` (or object instance that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) involved.

If that value doesn't change, just ditch the binding and use `x:Static` directly inside the `Text` property. Define `app` below to be the namespace (and assembly) location of the VersionManager class.

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Static app:VersionManager.FilterString}" />
```

If the value does change, I'd suggest creating a singleton to contain the value and bind to that.

An example of the singleton:

```cs
public class VersionManager : DependencyObject {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "FilterString", typeof( string ),
        typeof( VersionManager ), new UIPropertyMetadata( "no version!" ) );
    public string FilterString {
        get { return (string) GetValue( FilterStringProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( FilterStringProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static VersionManager Instance { get; private set; }

    static VersionManager() {
        Instance = new VersionManager();
    }
}
```

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:VersionManager.Instance},
                        Path=FilterString}"/>
```

Comment: Really? I've been able to do bind to the static Int32.MaxValue which is very similar to my sample:

<TextBox Text={Binding Source={x:Static sys:Int32.MaxValue}, Mode=OneWay}" />

Is that working because it's one way?

Comment: Yeah, any two way binding requires a Path property value on the binding. Source needs to be an object that contains the property specified by Path.

Specifying OneWay removes that restriction.

Comment: Also, sorry for the late update, but I updated the above answer with a sample.

Comment: Is there a way to bind a static string. I have a mutibinding and one of the input is a fixed string.

Answer (score 42):

In .NET 4.5 it's possible to bind to static properties, [read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#static_properties)

> You can use static properties as the source of a data binding. The
>   data binding engine recognizes when the property's value changes if a
>   static event is raised. For example, if the class SomeClass defines a
>   static property called MyProperty, SomeClass can define a static event
>   that is raised when the value of MyProperty changes. The static event
>   can use either of the following signatures:

```
public static event EventHandler MyPropertyChanged; 
public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
```

> Note that in the first case, the class exposes a static event named
>   PropertyNameChanged that passes EventArgs to the event handler. 
>   In the second case, the class exposes a static event named
>   StaticPropertyChanged that passes PropertyChangedEventArgs to the
>   event handler. A class that implements the static property can choose
>   to raise property-change notifications using either method.

Comment: Here's the link in case anyone wants to read more. Microsoft took it down, but it's on web archive here. 
https://web.archive.org/web/20131129053934/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb613588

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction, but it still took a while to work out the details without an example. I've written up an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428015/5024) based on the original code.

Answer (score 22):

As of WPF 4.5 you can bind directly to static properties and have the binding automatically update when your property is changed. You do need to manually wire up a change event to trigger the binding updates.

```cs
public class VersionManager
{
    private static String _filterString;        

    /// <summary>
    /// A static property which you'd like to bind to
    /// </summary>
    public static String FilterString
    {
        get
        {
            return _filterString;
        }

        set
        {
            _filterString = value;

            // Raise a change event
            OnFilterStringChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    // Declare a static event representing changes to your static property
    public static event EventHandler FilterStringChanged;

    // Raise the change event through this static method
    protected static void OnFilterStringChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = FilterStringChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(null, e);
        }
    }

    static VersionManager()
    {
        // Set up an empty event handler
        FilterStringChanged += (sender, e) => { return; };
    }

}
```

You can now bind your static property just like any other:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=(local:VersionManager.FilterString)}"/>
```

Comment: The `VersionManager` class can be static and everything still works. Note the braces in the path definition `Path=(local:VersionManager.FilterString)`. Does anyone know why they are actually needed?

Comment: The braces in the path definition are needed because the property is static, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax?redirectedfrom=MSDN#singleattached)

Comment: @Matt how do I know my wpf version?

Comment: Also note that unlike 'normal' binding you cannot omit `Path=` here

Answer (score 14):

There could be two ways/syntax to bind a `static` property. If **p** is a `static` property in class **`MainWindow`**, then `binding` for `textbox` will be:

**1.**

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Static local:MainWindow.p}" />
```

**2.**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.p},Mode=OneTime}" />
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `ObjectDataProvider` class and it's `MethodName` property. It can look like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="versionManager" ObjectType="{x:Type VersionManager}" MethodName="get_FilterString"></ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

Declared object data provider can be used like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource versionManager}}" />
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using local resources you can refer to them as below:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Resources.PerUnitOfMeasure}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Right variant for .NET 4.5 +

C# code

```
public class VersionManager
{
    private static string filterString;

    public static string FilterString
    {
        get => filterString;
        set
        {
            if (filterString == value)
                return;

            filterString = value;

            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, FilterStringPropertyEventArgs);
        }
    }

    private static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs FilterStringPropertyEventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs (nameof(FilterString));
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
}
```

XAML binding (attention to braces they are (), not {})

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=(yournamespace:VersionManager.FilterString)}" />
```

Comment: Made a slight change to your code to properly call the EventHandler.

Comment: Tried a lot of different solutions and this one worked. The PropertyChangedEventHandler is what worked for me. Cheers.

Comment: Using this for a DataTrigger.  Same - tried several methods and this worked

Answer (score 5):

Leanest answer (.net 4.5 and later):

```
    static public event EventHandler FilterStringChanged;
    static string _filterString;
    static public string FilterString
    {
        get { return _filterString; }
        set
        {
            _filterString= value;
            FilterStringChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

and XAML:

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=(local:VersionManager.FilterString)}"/>
```

Don't neglect the brackets

Answer (score 2):

Look at my project [CalcBinding](https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding), which provides to you writing complex expressions in Path property value, including static properties, source properties, Math and other. So, you can write this:

```
<TextBox Text="{c:Binding local:VersionManager.FilterString}"/>
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a normal class which implements PropertyChanger like this

```
public class ViewProps : PropertyChanger
{
    private string _MyValue = string.Empty;
    public string MyValue
    {
        get { 
            return _MyValue
        }
        set
        {
            if (_MyValue == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            SetProperty(ref _MyValue, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a static instance of the class somewhere you wont

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static ViewProps _ViewProps = null;
    public static ViewProps ViewProps
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ViewProps == null)
            {
                _ViewProps = new ViewProps();
            }
            return _ViewProps;
        }
    }
}
```

And now use it as static property

```
<TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind local:MyClass.ViewProps.MyValue, Mode=OneWay}"  />
```

And here is PropertyChanger implementation if necessary

```
public abstract class PropertyChanger : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class as follow:

```
public static class VersionManager 
{
    public static string FilterString;
}
```

You can bind your static variable in this way:

```
<TextBox Text = {x:Static local:VersionManager.FilterString }/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).