# Unable to Databind derived property in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I’ve got a property in a base class (view model), which when used in data binding in XAML doesn’t show up. It does however show up when I move that property to the derived view model. Why?

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock  Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
  Text="{Binding Path=ResxMessages.SelectPathToDevice}" />
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel{
    protected bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; set; }

    /*Putting this property here doesn't work*/
    private static Messages _resxMessages = null;
    public static Messages ResxMessages
    {
      get
      {
        if (_resxMessages == null)
            _resxMessages = new Messages();
        return _resxMessages;
      }
    }
}

public class MainViewModel :BaseViewModel{
    protected bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; set; }

    /*Putting this property here DOES work*/
    private static Messages _resxMessages = null;
    public static Messages ResxMessages
    {
      get
      {
        if (_resxMessages == null)
            _resxMessages = new Messages();
        return _resxMessages;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something because they are declared [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx(VS.80).aspx) (is this your intention or just accidentaly)?

Check the following post will help you further: [Binding to static property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/problem-binding-to-static-property)

Comment: Yep..that's it. Must've been trying different things and left that in. Thanks!