# WPF: static INotifyPropertyChanged event

Tags: wpf, binding

This is  my model:

```
class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static int Counter;
    public string _firstName;
    public string _lastName;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public string FirstName
   {
        get {return _firstname; }
        set
        {
            _fileName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("FirstName");                
        }
   }

   public AddPerson(Person person)
   {
       Counter++;
   }
}
```

I have this `NotifyPropertyChange` that changed all my `Persons` properties inside my `ListView` and i want to add the `Counter` field that hold the number of `Objects` that i have.
So is it possible to add another `PropertyChanged Event` for my `static` variable ?

Comment: Why don't you just reference the `Count` property in your `ListView`? There's no need for a counter.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614190/inotifypropertychanged-and-static-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a static counter you should have a view model with a collection of Person objects

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

and bind the `ItemsSource` property of the ListView to this collection.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    ...
</ListView>
```

You could now bind to the `Count` property of the collection to get the number of elements:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Persons.Count}"/>
```

---

For further reading see the *Binding to Collections* section in the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.