# INotifyPropertyChanged vs ObservableCollection for a single value

Tags: wpf, mvvm, static, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

In the examples for coding with the MVVM pattern and WPF binding, they use  `INotifyPropertyChanged` when it's a single value and `ObservableCollection` when it is a list of values.

I've also read, you cannot use static variables with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but you can with `ObservableCollection`. I'd like to bind to a static variable.

The easiest (to me at least) workaround, is to use an `ObservableCollection` and always just use and bind to index 0. Is this appropriate to do? Is there any benefit to using `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead of an `ObservableCollection`?

For example:
This seems to be the simplest workaround:

```
public static ObservableCollection<int> MyValues { get; set;  }

<TextBox Text="{Binding MyValue[0]}">
```

For wanting to do this:

```
private static int _myValue;
public static int MyValue //does not work
{ 
    get { return _myValue; }
    set { _myValue = value; OnPropertyChange(); }
}

<TextBox Text="{Binding MyValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Comment: "Is this appropriate to do?" If it works, then it works. As long as you don't encounter any performance issues, then I think it is fine. Because like you said, you can't use a static property with INotifyPropertyChanged. I don't know of any benefit of using INPC over an ObservableCollection, because they are usually used in different ways, but in this case, you can't use INPC on your static property.

Comment: You also might be interested in the accepted answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614190/inotifypropertychanged-and-static-properties

Comment: You can in theory do change notifications with a static property (`public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged`, blah blah) but... I've tried it, it didn't work, and your hack looks like a lot less trouble and would actually work. Thanks!

Comment: Wrap the property in a view model, put the view model in a static property. Done.

Comment: I would better move that static property to another class, make singleton out of it, and then bind as usual. At least looks not worse that using collection with single element for that.

Comment: You can also define regular (non-static) property in your view model, but make it reference static field in your getter\setter. This way you still do regular bindings but achieve the same effect as with static property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your analogy is fair(Comparing `ObservableCollection` with directly with `Primitive Type` property). Compare `ObservableCollection` to below class

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value;
        RaiseChange("Text");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaiseChange(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
    }
}
```

Now both below will behave same:

```
 public static MyClass Text { get; set; }

 public static ObservableCollection<string> Text { get; set; }
```

If you perform `Text.Text = "Hello"` for `MyClass`  or `Text[0] = "Hello"` for `ObservableCollection`, both will reflected in same way.

> ***Now if you have to use a static property for binding then instead of `ObservableCollection` I'll advice you to write your new class
>   cause `ObservableCollection` has many internal implementations which
>   probably is of no use to you any actually consuming memory &
>   perforamnce.***

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha) may help, it shows the difference between List, ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged.

Hope this help