# wpf using a static flag to update a property in a view model

Tags: c#, wpf

in my wpf application I am trying to change the window title bar depending on a specific static boolean variable. The idea is that no matter where I update this static flag the window title changes. If it's true then Title = "** Foo" else Title = "Foo".

**Attempt number one:**

I created a static boolean in my MainViewModel

```
public static bool RefreshTitleBar { get; set;}
```

And in my **MainWindowView.xaml** made this change:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Style.Triggers>
                Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static viewModel:MainViewModel.RefreshTitleBar}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Title" Value="--Foo"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static viewModel:MainViewModel.RefreshTitleBar}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Title" Value="Foo"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

But it doesn't update when RefreshTitleBar value changes. I have other properties working with binding so I know that's not the issue.

What am I missing here? Can someone help me understand why my title bar can't work? Is a title bar one of those things that simply can't be updated once it's set the first time? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You defined RefreshTitleBar as a `const`. Is that a typo? A `const` cannot be changed.

Comment: @Keithernet oops, that was my bad. I meant to just say static.

Comment: @ASh I made new changes as it was suggested in the link you provided (see updated code above) but my window title is still not being updated correctly. Thoughts?

Comment: _"I made new changes as it was suggested in the link"_ -- no, you didn't. You need to read _all_ the answers, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7515926).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is that your static property has no change notification. So your triggers will never fire.

You may want to consider having your `RefreshTitleBar` property as a standard `INotifyPropertyChanged` property, buy put it into a singleton class. This way you will only have one instance of the class for your whole application and you'll get the change notifications you need.

You can implement change notification for a static property, but it's a little more difficult.

[Binding static property and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680244/binding-static-property-and-implementing-inotifypropertychanged)

I hope this helps.