# Multibinding TextBox not updating with Combobox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selecteditem, multibinding

I'm trying to create a text preview of a file path by using `MultiBinding` in a `TextBlock` but I'm having an issue. What I would like to do is to set some values in some UI elements (one combobox and one textbox) and see the preview populating at the bottom of the window.
**Preview's XAML**

```
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Preview:"/>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="P:\{0}\{1}\file.txt">
                <Binding Path="SelectedStudio.Code"/>
                <Binding Path="SelectedProject.ProjectCode"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```

SelectedStudio and SelectedProject are properties in the ViewModel
**ViewModel**

```
    public ObservableCollection<WbStudio> Studios { get; set; }

    public static WbStudio SelectedStudio { get; set; }

    public static WbProject SelectedProject { get; set; }
```

**The objects**

```
public class WbProject
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class WbStudio
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

The properties of the ViewModel are bound to a different section of the UI at the top of the window
**Setup XAML**

```
    <Label Content="Project Studio:"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Studios, Mode=OneTime}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedValuePath="Code"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudio, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    <Label Content="Project Code:"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedProject.ProjectCode}"/>
```

Here is the **issue**:
The second Binding element in the Multibinding (`<Binding Path="SelectedProject.ProjectCode"/>`) will update and show up in the preview's TextBlock as soon as the TextBox above loses focus (perfect!), while the first Binding element (`<Binding Path="SelectedStudio.Code"/>`) never shows in the preview's TextBlock when I select an item from the ComboBox.

What am I missing and how do I fix it?
I thought it was a matter of implementing `OnPropertyChanged(string info)` for the `WbStudio` properties but that didn't work and `WbProject` doesn't have it implemented either so I thought that shouldn't be the issue. I also thought it might have to do with the properties being `static`, but they are both static and SelectedProject works. And you don't implement `OnPropertyChanged` methods the same way for static properties. So I'm suspecting it has to do with some difference between `Combobox` and `TextBox`?

Comment: I dont know how your collection looks like, but I think SelectedValuePath="Code"  is wrong. This means the Thing you want to set to Bound object is Code property.
later in the Multibinding you are expecting SelectedStudio.Code to exist.
Get rid of this SelectedValuePath - may be that works.

Comment: I just tried to get rid of it but still not working! The collection is simply a collection of that `WbStudio` objects (code in the post), but let me know if you need more info

Comment: ViewModel has to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire the PropertyChanged event for its properties, especially for SelectedStudio. As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the SelectedItem Binding is pointless. Both are set by default.

Comment: To who ever closed this question, the posted topic doesn't answer my question. As I said in the original post, I tried with INotifyPropertyChanged and it didn't work. ALSO, SelectedStudio is a static property so you don't implement OnPropertyChanged in the same way. Please re-open the question!

Comment: "*I tried with INotifyPropertyChanged and it didn't work*" is in no way a sufficient problem description. You have to implement that interface for non-static properties, and fire a StaticPropertyChanged event for static properties. If that doesn't work, show us what you did. Besides that, properties in a view model should never be static.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Clemens ! I didn't think of pasting the code for the OnStaticPropertyChanged as it wasn't working and I think that's not the problem, so I thought of avoiding confusion. But I took the code from the last two answers this other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680244/binding-static-property-and-implementing-inotifypropertychanged.  
Anyway the SelectedProject property is **static** too but that works in populating the <Binding...> element, so that's why I was thinking it wasn't a matter of that

Comment: `Path="SelectedStudio.Code"` is not valid for a static property. See the last linked original question and search StackOverflow. It should be something like `Path="(local:ViewModel.SelectedStudio).Code"`. However, these properties should not be static in the first place.

Comment: @Clemens I tried that now and still not working. Again, SelectedProject is bound using `<Binding Path="SelectedProject.ProjectCode"/>` and it works! That's why I was thinking it might be a difference between `ComboBox` and `TextBox`.  
Is it possible to re-open the question? Maybe someone is willing to help...

Comment: Better write a new question with all relevant details, but not more. Show us only what is not working, but show all details of your implementation. Also give a reason why these properties are static. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example