# Problem set ItemSource to static property in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have static property in a class that I need to set it as ItemSource for TreeView control.

some thing like that:

```
<TreeView x:Name="SegTreeView" Margin="199,55,240,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="88"
    ItemsSource="{x:Static local:STestFrameControl._sObserverList}">
```

when I run my app I get this run time exception:

> Cannot convert the value in attribute 'ItemsSource' to object of type 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension'.  Error at object 'SegmTreeView' in markup file 'DClient;component/stestframecontrol.xaml' Line 61 Position 99.

tries this solution: [Binding to static property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/problem-binding-to-static-property)

with no help.

thanks in advance, 
Evyatar

Comment: You need to provide the definition of the static property and the xaml that is being used to assign its usage.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. Are you sure you have the right `TreeView`? Your code and your error have different names. Also, what's the code of the property?

Comment: @Phil, the XAML was in the question, it just wasn't visible.