# How to bind a property in one assembly to another property in another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a class in assembly "AssemblyX" with property "Comment". I want to bind AssemblyX.Comment to TextBlock.Text in another assembly?

I'm trying to do it in the following way but it is not working.

```
<Window xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace;assembly=AssemblyX">
<TextBlock Text={Binding cc:Comment}/>
...
```

Comment: You probably meant: *I want to bind SomeClass.Comment in AssemblyX*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You usually don't bind to a property of a class, you bind to a property of an *instance* of a class. So in your codebehind you'd create an instance:

```
SomeNamespace.SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();
instance.Comment = "bla";
this.DataContext = intstance;
```

And in your xaml you bind:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Comment}"/>
```

In this case it absolutely does not matter in what assembly `SomeClass` is declared, as long as you current project references that assembly. It also doesn't matter what `SomeClass` is named. All that matters is that the instance you bind against has a property named `Comment`.

If the property of your class is static and you therefore don't have an instance, you can bind to the static property like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding cc:SomeClass.Comment}"/>
```

Comment: That was brilliant. I appreciate this answer.

Answer (score 0):

if your class is not static, you have to create an instance for your class. then you can bind to a property.

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/problem-binding-to-static-property) maybe it helps you

Answer (score 0):

To bind to a static property of a class ( static Command maybe ) try this

```
<MenuItem Header="{x:Static SomeClass.SomeProperty}"/>
```

Code behind

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static string SomePropety 
    { get { return "done"; } }
}
```