# DataGridComboBoxColumn data binding

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid, binding

I am trying to databind `DataGridComboBoxColumn`

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Number of Copies" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding NumberCopies}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
          <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding LifeAreaList}"/>
          <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
       </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

What I am doing wrong here , because I am getting an empty combobox in the run time .

---

I got following

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=LifeAreaList; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=49475561); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: And what error(s) are reported in the Output window when this runs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DataGridColumn` doesn't derive from `FrameworkElement` or `FrameworkContentElement` so it isn't in the visual tree and doens't have a `DataContext` and that's why your Binding is failing.

If the `List<int>` that you're binding to is the same for every item then maybe you should find another way to bind to it, maybe you could make it static and use `StaticResource` in the Binding.

Anyway, to bind `ItemsSource` to a `List<int>` property in your source class you can use `ElementStyle` and `ElementEditingStyle` (as pointed out by others). The following should work

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Number of Copies"
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ListAreaItem}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding LifeAreaList}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding LifeAreaList}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: ,thanks for your answer it looks interesting. If I make my List<int> static , how I can bind to it ? Could you please give me an example for this one.

Comment: @Night Walker: I'm not at my computer now but see the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/problem-binding-to-static-property

Comment: Now as I think deeper static will not help me because I need to get the selected item in the combobox ,And I will have a problem If I start using statics for those also.

Comment: @Night Walker: That will not be a problem. The ComboBoxes will share the ItemsSource but they will hace individual SelectedItems so that part already works for you. Your SelectedItemBinding can stay as it is

Comment: Thanks your example is really helpful and solved my issue . Could you please add also an example with static binding. I have tried and it not so worked in my case but probably I did something wrong (too new to xaml)

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to set the `ItemsSource` in the style, the column itself [has such a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.itemssource.aspx) which may override anything you may try to set in the style. Further, you try to set it in the wrong style (that style is for the display mode), you could try setting it in the `EditingElementStyle` instead, but i would not recommend that either.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting Items source in style?

Can you try this code:

```
 <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Number of Copies" >
                    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LifeAreaList}"  >
                               <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding .}"></Label>
                                </DataTemplate>
                               </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Define Data template for DataGridTemplateColumn if LifeAreaList is complex class collection and you want to display it in customized way.

Comment: I have tried like <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Number of Copies" ItemsSource="{Binding LifeAreaList}" > and I still see there empty comboboxes . Other columns with DataGridTextColumn binding working ok.

Comment: Can you try with TemplateColumn?

Comment: The same I am getting en empty combobox ,without the values I added there .

Answer (score 0):

I would try a regular DataGridColumn with PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" and see if you are are having a binding problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you would to use something similar to `DataGridCobmoboxColumn` may it be better to use the `DataGridTemplateColumn` you can use it and have the same functionality without need to use for `ItemsSource` `StaticResource`.

I set the root element in `RelativeSource` as `UserControl`, if your `DataGrid` is located inside a `Window` or `Page`, you will need to use them accordingly.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Number of Copies">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberCopies}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding NumberCopies, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.LifeAreaList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```