# DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource List Not Found

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Here is the class that is bound to the column. I set a watch on ListParts and the parts do in fact exist.

```
private MasksSourceList _MasksSourceListBound;
public MasksSourceList MasksSourceListBound
{
    get => _MasksSourceListBound;
    set { SetAndNotify(ref _MasksSourceListBound, value, () => MasksSourceListBound); }
}

public class MasksSourceList : ObservableObject
{
    private List<MaskDetail> _maskDetails;
    public List<MaskDetail> MaskDetails
    {
        get => _maskDetails;
        set { SetAndNotify(ref _maskDetails, value, () => MaskDetails); }
    }

    private List<Jarvis.Data.Models.Parts> _listParts;
    public List<Jarvis.Data.Models.Parts> ListParts
    {
        get => _listParts;
        set { SetAndNotify(ref _listParts, value, () => ListParts); }
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML that shows the parent items source of the DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding MasksSourceListBound.MaskDetails}" >
```

I am showing a normal text column to demonstrate the the ItemsSource binding of the DataGrid is working as shown in the attached image.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="part name"  Binding="{Binding PartName}">

    </DataGridTextColumn>

    <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
        Header="part name" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding MasksSourceListBound.ListParts}"
        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding PartName, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        SelectedValuePath="PartId"
        DisplayMemberPath="PartName" 
        >
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

But why does the ItemsSource of the combo box column does not recognize ListParts? I checked the spelling of PartId and PartName and they are correct.

Here is the error message from the Output Window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=MasksSourceListBound.ListParts; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=64358720); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

[image]

I have tried this instead but still no results:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MasksViewModel.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MasksViewModel.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

After modifying the above using DataContext.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts with the proper Relative Source etc. The tracer shows:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'DataContext.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=20088760): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=20088760): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=20088760): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.DataGridComboBoxColumn+TextBlockComboBox.ItemsSource (hash=46581119)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 66 : BindingExpression (hash=20088760): RelativeSource (FindAncestor) requires tree context
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=20088760): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=5618098): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=5618098): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
```

> Here is the corrected XAML 
>   Decided to explicitly set the datacontext for DataGrid to avoid 3 part binding. But still getting Input String was not in correct format in break mode. The output indicates RelativeSource (FindAncestor) requires tree context:

`<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding MasksSourceListBound}" ItemsSource="{Binding MaskDetails}"`

```
  <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="part name" HeaderStringFormat="             {0}" Width="200" 

                                            SelectedValueBinding="{Binding PartName, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            SelectedValuePath="PartId"
                                            DisplayMemberPath="PartName">
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                <Setter 
                                    Property="ItemsSource" 
                                    Value="{Binding DataContext.ListParts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
                                />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                <Setter 
                                    Property="ItemsSource" 
                                    Value="{Binding DataContext.ListParts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
                                />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: "Target element" is the object that owns the target of the binding. Here, that's the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element." means that it has no visual parent to inherit a `DataContext` from. [It's a common problem with that column type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7051313/424129).

Comment: I just tested using ElementStyle and EditElementStyle setting the ItemsSource there instead. Tried with finding ancestor to get the parent data context as well. But still no results. The MasksSourceListBound is within MasksViewModel which is the DataContext. Can you please provide the sample XAML?

Comment: The sample XAML is in the answer I linked. Where did `MasksViewModel` come from in the path in the Binding?

Comment: MasksViewModel is the DataContext of the Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we've gotten halfway there. The `DataContext` for the bindings in ElementStyle and EditingElementStyle is the row item -- `MaskDetail`, in your case. My guess is that this binding:

```
Value="{Binding MasksViewModel.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts}"
```

...is meant to suggest that the binding should find a viewmodel of type `MasksViewModel` and use the specified property from it.

That's not how bindings work, for one thing. They have a `DataContext` and if you don't specify `Source` or `RelativeSource` explicitly, they look for the property there. What's happening with that binding is it's looking at a `MaskDetail`, the row item class that you're populating the grid with, for a property named `MasksViewModel`. I don't think there is one, or this would work.

Here's a way to find out why bindings fail:

```
Value="{Binding MasksViewModel.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
```

Then watch the output pane in VS at runtime. You'll get traces for each step as the binding tries to find `MasksViewModel.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts` and you'll see where and why it fails.

So what you want to do, in the element styles, is bind to `ListParts`, a property of `MasksSourceListBound`, which in turn is a property of the main viewmodel -- which is the `DataGrid`'s `DataContext`.

So we search back up the visual tree to the `DataGrid`, get its `DataContext`, and look there for `MasksSourceListBound.ListParts`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter 
            Property="ItemsSource" 
            Value="{Binding DataContext.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
            />
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter 
            Property="ItemsSource" 
            Value="{Binding DataContext.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
            />
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

It's not beautiful, but it works consistently and that's the way we do things in WPF.

### Update

Here's a more complete picture of my XAML. I didn't recreate your whole thing exactly. The part that matters is the relative source binding: I can bind to properties of the DataGrid's DataContext using the following XAML. The DataGrid's DataContext is a reference to the main viewmodel -- the same object that owns `MasksSourceListBound.MaskDetails`.

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding MasksSourceListBound.MaskDetails}"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OtherTestProperty}" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
            Header="Test" 
            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            >
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter 
                        Property="ItemsSource" 
                        Value="{Binding DataContext.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" 
                        />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Using this sample, I am getting an Exception Unhandled message: Input string was not in a correct format. So, i removed the word DataContext and left in place MasksSourceListBound.ListParts which got rid of the Exception message, but as expected no results. Still need to find the data context somehow.

Comment: I'd have to see what you did to know what's wrong with it. I have my doubts about "Input string was not in a correct format". I pasted in that code from a test project where it worked.

Comment: When you type 'DataContext' is that literal or do you mean MyDataContext name ?

Comment: The relative source binding changes the source of the Binding to the `DataGrid` control. The `DataGrid` control has a property named `DataContext`. If the binding for `ItemsSource` is working, that `DataContext` property has a reference to your main viewmodel.

Comment: So the path `DataContext.MasksSourceListBound.ListParts`, on that binding, means "Go to the nearest ancestor that's a DataGrid. Get the value of the DataGrid's DataContext property. That object you get from DataContext should have a property called `MasksSourceListBound`. `MasksSourceListBound` should have a property called `ListParts`. Give me whatever's in `ListParts`."

Comment: Understood. I think the main culprit here is: RelativeSource (FindAncestor) requires tree context

Comment: Can I see the whole `<DataGridComboBoxColumn ...` element as it is now? The trace I see on that binding is very different.

Comment: I'm leaving the office in 20 minutes and for a weekend out of town. We need to get this wrapped up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146295/discussion-between-mikeg-and-ed-plunkett).

Comment: I'm in the chat room now.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me in the right direction with the XAML. I then only needed to changed the SelectedValuePath to PartName since MaskDetail only has the Name and not the Id.