# Converters not always working with XAML Windows Store Apps

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, converters

I've been using Converters to dynamically change stylings of my App depending on some conditions.

I found that the Converters does not always work properly.

Specifically, I found several instances where it was not working:

**Using Converter with Value**

```
    <Style x:Key="Style_TextBlock_Label_H4"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource Style_TextBlock_LabelBase}"
           TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter},
                                            ConverterParameter=LabelH4}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFAAAAAA" />
    </Style>
```

**Using Converter with Style of ContentControl**

```
<ContentControl Style="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LargeSizeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Style_ContentControl_Modifier_Radio_Minimal}">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Dovetail_UI_Register_Controls_Behaviors:PointerPressedToToggleBehaviorMinimal />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ContentControl>
```

For these 2 instances, so far they are not even entering the Converter itself.

**The Converter works fine if used with TextBlock styling though:**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock_ControlPrimaryContent_Popoutright"
                   Style="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LargeSizeConverter},ConverterParameter=Style_Button_ModifierPopoutRight_Minimal}"
                   Text="">
```

Any idea if I'm doing something wrong / better way of doing things? Or if this is not supported at all?

Thank you!

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8078525/3397793)

Answer (score 0):

Bindings in Style Setters are not supported in UWP/Store Apps.