# Checkbox binding to boolean twoway

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, binding, checkbox

I got a "settings" class (in a ownmade subfolder "etc" (in Visual studio)) it has a Boolean propertie named "boobackcolorred"(value = TRUE in the first form it puts it to true). Now I am making a WPF window for my settings and I want to use a checkbox where you can change the value of the boalean. I want to do this in the "XAML" way.(I can do it by making the event checked & unchecked but I don t want to do it that way.)

settings.cs: (in the "etc" folder I created in VS)

```
  class settings
    {

        public static Boolean boobackcolorred{ get; set; }
        ... // some extra code that does nothing with this, some xml reading and saving but doesn t matter for this issue.
    }
```

Now I am trying to do this with this xaml checkbox

```
 <CheckBox Content="Red Background?" Name="chbbackgroundred" IsChecked="{Binding etc.settings.boobackcolorred,Mode=TwoWay}" ></CheckBox>
```

OFC this isn t going to work I tried many ways of getting this to work. tried to include stuff like this:

```
xmlns:settings="clr-namespace:etc.myapp.settings"
```

also tried to bind the datacontext of the grid where the checkbox is in but no luck.

I know this can t be hard. However the answer will be greatly appreciated.

PS: it should be twoway binded so if unchecked the static boolean becomes false.

Comment: Two way binding is the default, so you don't have to explicitly code it.

Comment: Do you call OnPropertyChanged("boobackcolorred"); in your setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it's a static property.
Possible workaround in the answer here:

[Binding to static property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/problem-binding-to-static-property)

Answer (score 0):

Use IValueConverter interface.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource ChbCheckedConverter}}"/>
```

[Tutorial for using ValueConverters in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)