# Binding static class property to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, static

I would like to bind a `textbox` to a property of a static class. I would like this to be two-way binding. My static class is this (trimmed):

```
public static class ocrVar
{
    static ocrVar()
    {  
        MeterNumber = new Element();
    }
}
```

The Element class looks like this (trimmed):

```
public class Element
    {

        public List<string> Value { get; set; }

        public Element()
            : this(new List<string>())
        {
        }
        public Element(List<string> value)
        {
        Value = value;
        }
    }
```

If I want to take a `TextBox` and bind it to ocrVar.MeterNumber.Value[0], is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please read [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), specifically **Sample code and data**. It's good that you include a sample of your code, but please keep it as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's **static** class , and you want to perform **two-way binding**, you have supply the path and provide a class is not static as a trick and use the binding

in your case, would be

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ocrVar x:Key="ocrVarManager"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ocrVarManager}, Path=MeterNumber.Value[0]}"/>
```

you can refer to [Binding to Static Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property)

Comment: When I try this, I get "The type 'local:ocrVar was not found."