# One way binding to static property fails

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, static

I have problem with binding to static property. 
I want to have `Label` with `Content` ***true*** or ***false*** depending on the value of **bool** variable.

XAML:

```xml
<Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static l:MainWindow.IsTrue}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Code behind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static bool IsTrue { get; set; }
    DispatcherTimer myTimer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        myTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2); // tick every 2 seconds
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
        myTimer.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsTrue = !IsTrue;
    }
}
```

It displays **False** all the time.

I know that in order to implement **two way binding** [I need to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property) specify `Path`. But I need one way binding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that WPF doesn't know when (or if) your property changes.  Unlike an instance method, there is no `INotifyPropertyChanged`-style interface you can implement, since you can't have a "static interface."  As such, it never sees your changed value.

If you're using WPF 4.5, you can use the new [static property changed notification support](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties) to handle this.

In .NET 4.0 or earlier, the easiest way to handle this is typically to wrap the property into a singleton, and use `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the singleton instance.