# Binding to static texts from An Infrastructure assembly in Prism

Tags: c#, prism

I want to bind the titles of the Views to static text's from our Infrastructure's Titles Class.
Adding a symbol prefix (e.g "**Ref**") and registering it's namespace and use it in the View
What I want is to achieve something similar to this :

**Part1:**

```
xmlns:Ref="clr-namespace:Xz.Infrastructure;assembly=Xz.Infrastructure"
```

**Part2:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Titles.Title1}" />
```

Hopefully a way more similar to :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Ref:Titles.Title1}" />
```

Please correct me.

**Part3:**

```
namespace Xz.Infrastructure
{
    public class Titles
    {
        public static string Title1 = "Title1";
        public static string RgnContent = "RgnContent";
    }
}
```

- Our **Infrastructure** isn't defined as a module, it's just an assembly.
- The Project is using Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a static string you can simply use:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static Ref:Titles.Title1}"/>
```

If you really do want this bound and supporting change notification and such, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936331/1416220)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
{Binding Source={x:Static MyNamespace:MyStaticClass.MyStaticStringField}}
```

So

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static Xz.Infrastructure:Titles.Title1}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this, Couldn't I omit the "Xz.Infrastructure" and instead use the "Ref" ?

Comment: I'am happy to help you @Sypress, yes you can use prefix Ref