# Is it possible to bind to Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8

I have a control with a value that I would like to be mapped to `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MyValue"]`.

Can I bind to this variable directly or do I need to add a viewmodel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, you would need the `x:Static` markup extension, which unfortunately [is unavailable on Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property).

So, just assign a viewmodel to your page, and expose the value in a property:

```
public string MyValue
{
    get
    {
        return Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MyValue"];
    }
}
```

Or you can expose the whole dictionary:

```
public Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer Settings
{
    get
    {
        return Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    }
}
```

Then bind it from the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Settings[MyValue]}" />
```