# Array of class from code behind to xaml

Tags: wpf, arrays, xaml, code-behind

I want to display in xaml data of class array defined in app.xaml.cs.

Heres what i did.

Class that holds the data. Person.cs

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Constructors and Destructors

    public Person(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Id = id;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Events

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Person is declared in App.xaml.cs like so.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static Person[] People =
        {
            new Person(1, "John"),
            new Person(2, "Jake"),
            new Person(3, "James"),
            new Person(4, "Jack")
        };
}
```

I want to display the data in xaml. I cant seem to figure out how to do it.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="id"/>
        <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="name"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="id"/>
        <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="name"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="id"/>
        <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="name"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="id"/>
        <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="name"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally using an `ItemsControl` or one of its subclasses is the way to go. If you wanted the xaml exactly as entered in the original post, this would be the way to do it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:a="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <StackPanel DataContext="{x:Static a:App.People}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding [0].Id}"/>
      <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding [0].Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding [1].Id}"/>
      <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding [1].Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding [2].Id}"/>
      <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding [2].Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding [3].Id}"/>
      <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding [3].Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

For more about property paths in xaml, take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an collection control, for example an `ItemsControl` and bind its `ItemsSource` to your static property:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Id}" />
            <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You should not use a static property, but instead have a service which is injected into your view model (which is acting as the data context for this view), and ensure this service is a singleton.

You will also need to invoke the `PropertyChanged` event in the setters of your `Person` properties for the UI to be notified.

If you want to persist with the static property, then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property).

Comment: Thank you very much! I must agree with you that using item control would be a better choice.