# Bindable(event="...") public static function

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, binding, mxml

I am trying to bind to a static function, I designate a binding event name and then fire the event from another static function.

```
[Bindable(event="dataUpdated")]
public static function string(path:String) :String
{
    ...
}

private static function updateData() :void
{
    //doSomthing;
    staticEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new Event('dataUpdated'));
}

private static var staticEventDispatcher:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
```

My view is not updating when the event is fired, is there a better way to do this?

I have also tried dispatching the event from an instance of the class, I added this `staticEventDispatcher` as a last resort, but it didn't work.

---

The point in this if for language translations within the app, `MyClass.string('stringPath')` will return the translated component text. I need the app text to be updated when the user changes their language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding doesn't work with static properties and methods (see this question for details [Binding to static property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property)).

In your case it's better to use the singleton pattern for resource manager and remove `static` from `string` and `updateData`:

```
MyClass.instance.string('stringPath')
```

and `MyClass`:

```
public static const instance:MyClass = new MyClass();
```