# wpf #define equivalent to set a two different standard button widths ... application.resources?

Tags: wpf, equivalent

How does one set a value (similar to `#define`) that sets two different standard button widths (MinWidth) ... perhaps using application.resources?  Buttons later use one of the standards defines.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you could define multiple button styles in a resource dictionary, and then set your button's style to the desired one.

In resource definition:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="Key_Button_Wide">200</sys:Double>

    <Style x:Key="ButtonWide" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Width" Value="{DynamicResource Key_Button_Wide}" />
    </Style>
```

Then your button could use this style when you define it:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonWide}" />
```

You could also bind your width to a static property, check out this post:
[Binding to static property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property)