# WPF 4.5 Binding to static properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a static property in my class like

```
  public partial class ShellWindow
          {
            private static Visibility progressbarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            public static Visibility ProgressbarVisibility
            {
              get { return progressbarVisibility; }
              set
              {
                if (progressbarVisibility == value) return;
                progressbarVisibility = value;
               RaiseStaticPropertyChanged("ProgressbarVisibility");
              }
            }
           public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
           public static void RaiseStaticPropertyChanged(string propName)
           {
            EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> handler = StaticPropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            handler(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
     }
    }
```

I am creating a control in code behind and wanted to bind it with this property.
Currently i am doing like this

```
var binding = new Binding("ShellWindow.ProgressbarVisibility") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
  binding.Source = this;
  progressbar = new CircularProgressBar ();
  progressbar.SetBinding(VisibilityProperty,
                             binding);
```

This binding is not working.
I am tring to follow this [article](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/28/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-9-binding-to-static-properties/) but i didn't get where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Take a look at this post, I think it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4.5 you can notify WPF of a change to a static property, however I believe it is different than how you normally handle a property changed. You must create event for each static property that can be notified of a change. The event must be titled with the property name, and have a suffix of PropertyChanged.

I found this article that may help you out: http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties