# Binding to an Static property of an Static class doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to `Bind` the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` to `StaticClass.Percent`. Since I couldn't do that (Or could I?) I have defined the `LoadingPercent` in my `ViewModel` so that I can bind to it. It is still not working. How can I solve this? Or can I bind to the StaticClass directly and ignore the ViewModel approach?

```
<Window x:Class="TestBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:testBinding="clr-namespace:TestBinding"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <testBinding:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Width="100" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{Binding LoadingPercent}"/>
        <Button Content="Change" 
                Width="200" 
                Height="30" 
                Margin="0 20 0 0" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Click="ChangeText"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ChangeText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StaticClass.Percentage = 10;
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double loadingPercent;
    public double LoadingPercent
    {
        get { return StaticClass.Percentage; }
        set
        {
            loadingPercent = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LoadingPercent");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public static class StaticClass
{
    public static int Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a mistake:

```
private double loadingPercent;
public double LoadingPercent
{
    get { return StaticClass.Percentage; }
    set
    {
        loadingPercent = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("LoadingPercent");
    }
}
```

You return in `get` the `StaticClass.Percentage` but you assign `loadingPercent` in set.

I am not sure why you need the static class after all, but if you want to ditch the viewmodel and bind directly to the static property, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property)

Comment: I'm doing some calculations in the static class which I need to show in the TextBlock in real-time. I've tried the accepted answer in the link you just gave, but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: If you modify the static class property, then there is no way for the view to get the modification. You have to use `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: But I can't use `INotifyPropertyChanged` in an static class.