# Using static method for binding in windows store apps

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a static class with certain functions to give path of assets. Currently I am just creating wrapper around those function in all the viewmodels for binding. I was wondering if there was some way in windows phone 8.1 to bind the static function directly to the image source.
In wpf Objectdataprovider  would have been useful but it is not supported in windows store apps. I was unable to find any documentation as well.

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
 <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" 
             ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath"/>
 </Rectangle.Fill>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you modify the functions into properties? if so, you can bind to static property like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property)

Comment: Tried that before. Getting this error "The type FooBar is abstract and must include an explicit value"
I havent converted the class to non static though.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using functions instead of properties? `ImagePath` seems like it should be a property instead of a function.

Comment: Sure I can use it as a property as well. The problem is binding to static function/property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's (currently) not possible to bind to a static class as binding requires an object instance. You can, however, bind to static properties of a class.

You create a instance wrapper around your static class:

```
public class BindingHelper
  {
    public static string ImagePath
    {
      get { return AssetHelper.ImagePath; }
    }
  }
```

Now create an application resource for this BindingHelper:

```
<application.resources>
  <BindingHelper x:key="BindingHelperResource"></BindingHelper >
</application.resources>
```

And use this resource for your Binding:

```
<textblock text="{Binding Path=ImagePath, Source={StaticResource BindingHelperResource}}">
```

Comment: I am unable to find BindingHelper in windows phone 8.1.

Comment: You create the BindingHelper class. It is just a wrapper around your static class. Also replace the AssetHelper.Image path with the name of your actual static class and static method.

Comment: That worked. I think it was because of using static function that I was getting errors. Good to know. Thanks!!