# How to reference a .resx file in a Windows 8.1 (WinRT) app?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

In my solution I have the following project types:

**Views**

- Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal)
- Windows 8.1 (Universal)
- Windows Phone 8.0

**View Model**

- Portable project (namespace xxx.Common)

### View Model

In the portable project I have a`.resx` file with `Access Modifier` set to `Public` (portable projects only support `.resx` files)

```
xxx.Commom\Resources\ViewResources.resx
```

Then to access the resource I have a wrapper called `ResourceAccess.cs`, I have to make a wrapper because `.resx` generates an `internal` constructor.

```
namespace xxx.Common.Resources
{
    public class ResourceAccessor
    {
        private static ViewResources _appResources;
        public static ViewResources AppResources
        {
            get
            {
                if(_appResources== null)
                {
                    _appResources= new ViewResources();
                }
                return _appResources;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### View

In the View for both Windows Phone 8.0 and Windows 8.1 projects I have a file called `LocalizedStrings.cs`

```
using xxx.Common.Resources;
namespace xxx
{
    public class LocalizedStrings
    {
        public ViewResources LocalizedResources { get { return ResourceAccessor.AppResources; } }
    }
}
```

#### App.xaml file

Windows Phone 8.0 project

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Windows 8.1 shared project

```
<Application
xmlns:local="using:xxx">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:LocalizedStrings  x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

#### Main.xaml

In the Windows Phone 8.0 project this works:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.CommonResxText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
```

But in the Windows 8.1 project the above does not work.

**How do you reference a string in a `.resx` file in Windows 8.1 (WinRT)?**

I have had a look at [Using string resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965326.aspx) from MSDN, but that does not help me, since I cannot change the `resx` into a `resw` in a portable project (that literally only references `.Net`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long stare at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property) question

I saw that my bindings in my Windows 8.1 project was wrong, and this is the correct binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=LocalizedResources.CommonResxText}"/>
```

#### P.S.

This approach works... in `Debug`

When the project is in `Release` it doesn't.

In the auto-generated file `ViewResources.Designer.cs`

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("CommonResxText", resourceCulture);
```

throws an exception, because the strings don't exist in the assembly; they're not compiled into the binary in `Release`

Read more about this issue [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2014/11/19/missingmanifestresourceexception-when-using-portable-class-libraries-in-winrt.aspx)

Comment: Huge +1 for the link to the msdn blog post. That saved my day, and by extension, the release of my current project!

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need all the wrapper classes? Why not referring to the resource file contents directly?

To do so, you simply make the resource file generate code (with Access Modifier: Public in the combo box at the .resx screen) and then bind the text directly to the view, like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static resx:ViewResources.MyText}" />
```

Just make sure to add resx as the xml namespace at your Window/UserControl:

```
<Window xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:xxx.Common.Resources" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work, gives error: Static is not supported in Windows Phone/App project