# Binding to static array in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to bind an item source in my WPF to a static array. I have tried to do this by writing:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding XLTT.Core.Models.names}"
```

But it doesn't work. Why? Additionally, I have seen others bind to objects. Is it ok to bind to a static array or should I be binding to an object instead?

EDIT:

Here is the class with `names` definition.

```
namespace XLTT.Core.Models
{
    internal class TTColumn
    {
        internal string ColumnName;
        internal string ColumnType;
        internal int ColumnOrder;
        internal bool IsRequired;
        internal int ColumnWidth;

        public static string[] names = {"Matt", "Joanne", "Robert"};
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is defined your static array? Can you show us the class with its definition?

Comment: As long as array is not private and it's property it's OK. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property

Comment: @Maximus: tried writing ItemsSource="{Binding x:Static local:XLTT.Core.Models.names} but that didn't work

Answer (score 2):

For starters, Names needs to be **property**

```
public static string[] Names {get; set;}
```

Then bind as follows:

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TTColumn}, Path=Names}"
```

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XLTT.Core.Models}, Path=Names}" gives the error Error "The resource "XLTT.Core.Models" could not be resolved.". Do you know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Namespace is unnecessary.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Do I need to define the resource somehow among my other resources?     <controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window
...
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:XLTT.Core.Models">

ItemsSource="{x:Static m:TTColumn.names}"
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23987439)