# Two way binding of a static property of static class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, two-way-binding

Is there any GOOD way to bind a static property of static class in a two way mode?

Here is an example class:

```
 static class SettingsModel
 {
        static public string ModelFolder { set; get; }
 }
```

And a text box:

```
<TextBox x:Name="ModelTB" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:SettingsModel.ModelFolder}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=???/>
```

I've been searching for a lot and I've found only 2 not really good answers: Make class not static or create a dummy window resource class.

Comment: [Binding to static property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property)

Comment: You want [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7515926) in the marked duplicate, as it shows how to do this without intermediate objects.

Comment: I've added another duplicate which explains how you would do it since WPF 4.5