# Binding static assessors wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, static, accessor

Good morning.

I would like to keep values in a class with public static assessors. For example:

```
public class Global
{
     public static string Information { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

And I want to change these values from UI level. I've tried do it this way:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static Member=local:Global.Information}}"/>
```

But there occurred an error:

```
Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.
```

I was looking for answer but every solution isn't working for me.

How can I bind static accessor from class with Text property?

Comment: Now there is error: Expected 'Information' on type 'Global' to be an instance member. So still it isn't working.

Comment: I misread that, sorry. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [PropertyPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax) syntax for static properties, which is available since WPF 4.5:

```
Text="{Binding Path=(local:Global.Information)}"/>
```