# Binding to Binding Locator in XAML does not work

Tags: xamarin.forms, service-locator, common-service-locator

I have a Xamarin Forms Application with MvvmLight using the Service Locator Pattern. The ViewModelServiceLocator itself is a static class with access to a Autofac container with all dependencies registered. For each VM there is static property:

```
    public static AboutViewModel AboutVm => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AboutViewModel>();
```

I have the Locator setup as in my App as a resource follows:

```
<presentation:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
```

And in my xaml on my page:

```
BindingContext="{Binding AboutVm, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

But the Locator is never called.
But it does work, when I set it up in the code behind via

```
BindingContext = ViewModelLocator.AccountListVm;
```

Do I miss a resource definition or something?

Comment: Can you try give a path as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936304/binding-to-static-property)?

Comment: It does work when I use the static reference. But it would be nice to have the option to have it via the resource, so it is identical to UWP.